# Bash Conditional Statements

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, command-line-interface

I am currently working on a script that clones a Wordpress install from a master template and edits the sql database accordingly.

I have different templates to choose from so I need a conditional statement which is what I am having trouble with.
When I run my script it just runs everything completely disregarding my conditions.

---

```
#!/bin/sh

sed 's/wpruser123/"$VIRTUALSERVER_USER"/g' "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wp-config1.php > tmp_file
mv tmp_file "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wp-config2.php
sed 's/wprpass123/"$VIRTUALSERVER_PASS"/g' "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wp-config2.php > tmp_file
mv tmp_file "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wp-config.php
rm "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wp-config1.php
rm "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wp-config2.php


if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_TEMPLATE" = '149505977015116' ]; then
mysqldump trueblue > "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
chmod +x "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
sed s/trueblue.dev.example.com/"$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM"/g "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql > tmp_file
mv tmp_file "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
mysql --user="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" --password="$VIRTUALSERVER_PASS" --database="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" < "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
fi 

if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_TEMPLATE" = '149505982215162' ]; then
mysqldump polishedpro > "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
chmod +x "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
sed s/polishedpro.dev.example.com/"$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM"/g "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql > tmp_file
mv tmp_file "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
mysql --user="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" --password="$VIRTUALSERVER_PASS" --database="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" < "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
fi

if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_TEMPLATE" = '149505993915397' ]; then 
mysqldump luminous > "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
chmod +x "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
sed s/luminous.dev.example.com/"$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM"/g "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql > tmp_file
mv tmp_file "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
mysql --user="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" --password="$VIRTUALSERVER_PASS" --database="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" < "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
fi

if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_TEMPLATE" = '149505987915222' ]; then
mysqldump steadyscroll > "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
chmod +x "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
sed s/trueblue.dev.example.com/"$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM"/g "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql > tmp_file
mv tmp_file "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
mysql --user="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" --password="$VIRTUALSERVER_PASS" --database="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" < "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
fi

if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_TEMPLATE" = '149505991515361' ]; then
mysqldump evenkeel > "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
chmod +x "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
sed s/evenkeel.dev.example.com/"$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM"/g "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql > tmp_file
mv tmp_file "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
mysql --user="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" --password="$VIRTUALSERVER_PASS" --database="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" < "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
fi

if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_TEMPLATE" = '149505995815433' ]; then
mysqldump cleanslate > "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
chmod +x "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
sed s/cleanslate.dev.example.com/"$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM"/g "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql > tmp_file
mv tmp_file "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
mysql --user="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" --password="$VIRTUALSERVER_PASS" --database="$VIRTUALSERVER_USER" < "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
fi

rm "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb.sql
rm "$VIRTUALSERVER_HOME"/public_html/wprb2.sql
```

Comment: Where are your variables set? Also you have tagged bash but are running sh.

Comment: Try adding `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so it'll print its interpretation of the script commands as it executes them.

Comment: Try to change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Can you simplify your problem? Maybe only show a single `if` condition

Comment: Where are you defining `VIRTUALSERVER_TEMPLATE`? I would check its value.

Comment: This **really** needs a [mcve] to be an acceptable question here. A question containing code should have *the smallest possible amount of code that generates the same problem* -- and it should be *verifiable*, letting others see the problem for themselves with as little setup as possible (code that requires someone else to have a specific MySQL database available *definitely* isn't verifiable by anyone but you).